# Is it possible to globally disable some settings in Eclipse, or override project-specific settings?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to globally disable some settings in Eclipse, or override project-specific settings?
In particular, make it so that save actions and code style is never applied, regardless of project settings I don't want Eclipse mucking with the code, ever, even if the project says it should, without explicitly performing code cleanup/etc.
Otherwise, all my patches have some bogus random changes in the places I never even touched and I have to go and disable it for every project.